# Is there a way to ignore a node_module when running npm install

Tags: npm-install, node-modules

Hi I have made some custom adjustments to a node_module's files to get it to meet client requirements. These changes obviously are not in the packages source code so I want to avoid overwritting them if I need to update npm packages. Is there a way to do this? Maybe something similar to a git ignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying a npm package directly is not recommended and could lead to multiple issues, the way to go about this is either contribute your changes to the original source code on GitHub if other would find the code you wrote useful, either that or you could make your own fork of the package and use that as a dependency instead.

You can install your own package by using the tarballs provided by GitHub.

`npm install https://github.com/<username>/<repository>/tarball/master`

Comment: Thanks I wasn't thinking of the drawbacks and think forking is the way to go right now.